How to copy multiple columns? (not in sequence)
I need to get a range form an excel sheet and use in this code to copy and paste it on a powerpoint presentation. I think the range doesnt work like that anymore but I dont have any idea on another way of doing that, any tips?

Sub PPTableMacro()
    
    Dim oPPTApp As PowerPoint.Application
    Dim oPPTShape As PowerPoint.Shape
    Dim oPPTFile As PowerPoint.Presentation
    Dim SlideNum As Integer
    
    Dim strPresPath As String, strExcelFilePath As String, strNewPresPath As String
    strPresPath = "filepath"
    strNewPresPath = "filepath"

    Set oPPTApp = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    oPPTApp.Visible = msoTrue
    Set oPPTFile = oPPTApp.Presentations.Open(strPresPath)
    SlideNum = 1
    oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select
    
    'Set oPPTShape = oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Shapes("ws22")
    
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET")
    Set Table = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET").range("A2:A15,D2:D15,J2:J15,L2:L15,R2:R15")
    Table.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture '<------ERROR HERE!
    'SlideNum = SlideNum + 1
    
    oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPastePicture)
    oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select

End Sub

EDIT: thanks for all the answers and ideas!!! Saw this post and it worked for me:
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET")
    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SHEET").Activate
    Set rngToCopy = Application.Union(range("A2:A15"), range("D2:D15"), range("J2:J15"), range("L2:L15"), range("R2:R15"))
    rngToCopy.Copy
    ws.range("AA1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    'Table.CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture

    oPPTFile.Slides(1).Shapes.PasteSpecial (ppPastePicture)
    oPPTFile.Slides(SlideNum).Select



What error do you get? Try to use the 2, -4147 (long values for the picture parameters) instead of  xlPrinter, xlPicture on the copy picture line.

CopyPicture doesn't work on mulitple selections. The source range to be copied must consist of a continuous block of cells. In your case, you may need to copy each area of the table separately.


 Range("A2:A15,D2:D15,J2:J15,L2:L15,R2:R15").CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture


I quick test in Excel indicates that the Range.CopyPicture does not work on multiple selections.

I would add another worksheet to the Excel file and gather the data into a single block of contiguous (connected) cells.
Black cat is right in pointing out the OP is running the file from Excel and will need a reference to the Power Point library.  I assume he does because the use PowerPoint.Application.

I think if you have not referenced an application you cannot Dim it.

Thanks @Blackcat.  I knew the problem was the multiple ranges and did not look closer at the code.  I updated my answer.

Great idea! pretty simple and practical. Also I have already referenced the library. Thanks!!!

CopyPicture doesn't work on mulitple selections. The source range to be copied must consist of a continuous block of cells. (@TinMan posted the answer before my comment)
There is a workaround to copy non-continuous columns all at once.
Note: The script may not work perfectly for all non-continuous ranges and has only been tested for the original poster's scenario.
Sub CopyMultiAreasRange()
    Dim sRng As Range, firstC As Range, lastC As Range
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Set sRng = .Range("A2:A15,D2:D15,J2:J15,L2:L15,R2:R15")
        Set firstC = sRng.Areas(1).Cells(1)
        With sRng.Areas(sRng.Areas.Count)
            Set lastC = .Cells(.Cells.Count)
        End With
        For i = firstC.Column To lastC.Column
            If Intersect(sRng, .Columns(i)) Is Nothing Then
                .Columns(i).Hidden = True
            End If
        Next
        Range(firstC, lastC).CopyPicture xlPrinter, xlPicture
        ' *** for testing
        .Activate
        .Range("A18").Select
        .Paste
        ' ***
        .Columns.Hidden = False
    End With
End Sub



i didnt test it but thanks for your time! :)
